# Trouble getting SSL encryption to work with load balance (HTTPS redirect problem)

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, encryption, https

I have a question regarding SSL encryption for streaming server.

I have a load balancer connected to main panel and both have SSL certs installed properly. However, when the stream is hosted in load balancer, the main panel redirects requests to Load balancer's protected stream link using a simple temporary token over HTTP, and I want encrypted credentials to be sent over HTTPS.  I have tried using a redirect to HTTPS, but a sniffer shows that the HTTP header contains the streaming credentials in clear text, when I want them encrypted.

I don't have access to the streaming server and the files are encrypted, so I can't edit the server configs to force the HTTPS redirect. However, through the admin panel, I can add the domain of load balancer, so, for example, if my domain is Server.com, the main panel redirects to the load balancer using this format:

`http://server.com?token=djnsjkdnjsnas`.

Is there any way to write the domain name in a way, such as `https://server.com`, that will result in a redirect URL something like something like `http://https://server.com`, while ignoring the HTTP header and using HTTPS instead?

BTW, the streaming server is xtream iu, or the upgraded version of xtream codes.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, always provide a [mcve] with your question. It also helps to format your text a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first post so had no idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To force https on the load balancer you need to send a simple command to your mysql database, via terminal,by default, xtream codes will use http,  login to your mysql  via putty then type in "UPDATE xtream_iptvpro.settings SET use_https='["1"]' WHERE id='1';"  or you can apply the same update via phpMiniAdmin if your xtream build supports it, this will  force https in the m3u playlist, add the id number of your load balancer to apply the changes. I used 1 as an example it wont be 1 that will be your main server so adjust accordingly. Also the ssl certs on both the main and load balancers will need to match the root domain, if you install individual ssl certs for each domain it will fail and wont stream. So you will need to use a multi ssl cert. Some will cover up to 100 domains on the same cert.